# Is it possible to close a GitHub/GitLab repository?

Tags: github, gitlab

I haven't found anything about closing a GitHub/GitLab repository. I guess it's not feasible.

By "closed", I mean: it's possible to browse it/clone it, but not to create new commits/branches.

Maybe there is some kind of equivalent or other way to achieve this on either GitLab or GitHub for this? Bonus point if there is a readable error or message somewhere stating that the repo is closed.

Comment: I assume by git/gitlab you mean github/gitlab as git is only the software and github is no official repo. You have ownership of the repository you wanted to close?

Comment: @Matteo Originally I wrote git as in the software behind (not sure if the server-side can be called 'git' though). It was edited as github anyway. But I was wondering if this could have been done with the server-side git. I don't have ownership but I can ask to.

Comment: @Asoub I thought you meant GitHub/GitLab there. Doing that on the `git` server itself is a whole different thing. You can edit the question if you want, but you would probably be better off asking a different question since the two things are very different.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Ok I see. This would have been plan B if it was not available on gitlab, but as there is a way it won't be necessary. I'll wait a little then probably accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On **GitHub**, you can "archive" a repository, making it read-only, which seems exactly what you're looking for. You can find a button to do so right in the settings of your repo, that is `https://github.com/<username>/<repository>/settings`. A banner will be shown stating that the repository is archived and no further modifications (e.g. new commits or branches) are possible. See [this help page](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/archiving-repositories) for more info.

[image: archive button]

On **GitLab**, the same thing can be done from Settings > General > Advanced settings > Archive project. See [this help page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/#archiving-a-project).